# Web Project is Build successfully in Visual Studio 2017 without any error but still it showing as error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am Using Visual Studio 2017 as IDE for developing asp.net mvc based web application. In asp.net Project i have referrenced the class library application for three tier architecture. When I build the solution, it builds successfully and could ran also. But when I see my project code it shows like "are you missing directive or an assembly reference error" in many places. Because of that code intelligence is not working. Even I have to do build for single code change to check whether any of the compilation error exists in my code.

I have did the following, but not helped any how,

1. Clean solution --> And rebuild the solution
2. Restart the Visual studio and rebuild the solution
3. Removing the .suo file in solution directory

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: post your code up to a GitHub repo so we can see it.

Comment: did you try making the new project, copying things into it, from scratch really. And there're posts on this already did you try search, post what you have found and why that is not a good fit for you.

Comment: Thanks @JoeHealy for commenting..  I resolved this issue by reinstalling the EntityFramework library to all the project in the solution. After that it works fine.But dont know why it behaves like that and dependency between the entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by reinstalling the EntityFramework library to all the project in the solution. After that it works fine.